# Rational numbers imply reals?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, approximation, rational-numbers, real-numbers

I was solving an inequality today and I proved it for rational numbers (it was easier because I was able to "strengthen" by doing things like "$\frac{p}{q}>\frac{r}{s}\implies ps\ge qr+1$ since $ps,qr\in \mathbb{Z}^+$". I then noted that "since it is proven for rationals, it must be true for reals, since every real can be approximated by rationals arbitrarily". Is this wrong? I wasn't sure of this step.

Thanks!

EDIT: Problem: If $a,b>0$, prove that:

$$\frac{1}{a+b+1}-\frac{1}{(a+1)(b+1)}<\frac{1}{11}$$

I plugged $a=p/q$ and $b=r/s$ and proved it to be true in the case where $q\ge p$, i.e. $a\le 1$. I then plugged $a\rightarrow 1/a$ and showed it to be true in this case, so it must be true for all positive $a,b$ that are rational. I then said it follows for reals, but this is the step I wasn't sure.

EDIT#2: My question is basically, can you show me how to rigorous prove that if this inequality holds for positive rationals, then it must hold for positive reals?

Comment: What is the equivalent statement for reals? Real numbers can't be expressed as ratios, so what does it mean to "be true for reals?"

Comment: @user45220 To expand on what mixedmath is saying, your statement $ps,\,qr\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ is contradictory if $p,\,q,\,r,\,s$ are irrational.

Comment: I think the problem is that the OP was "solving **an** inequality" and proved it for rationals (using the technique he describes). Whether the inequality (which the OP sadly does not mention) also holds for all reals in that case of course depends on the given inequality. So, @user45220: What is the inequality you were solving?

Comment: $P$ holds for all reals if and only if (1) $P$ holds for all rationals and (2) if $P$ holds for elements in a Cauchy sequence $(q_1, q_2, \dots) \to x$, then $P$ holds for $x$.

Comment: If a continuity argument is available, then yes. But note that for example if $x$ is rational then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(2\pi x n!)=0$, while the statement is not necessarily true if $x$ is real. So one would have to know more about your specific problem to answer the question.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks. I don't know "continuity argument", but I can show you the problem. I will edit now, it will be there in a few seconds.